# Executar um script em shell com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou precisando criar uma página usando nodejs, que conterá um botão "Liga / Desliga". Ao pressionar este botão pretendo fazer a chamada da mesma rota, porém passando um parâmetro: liga/desliga ou 0/1, etc.. Ao fazer essa chamada, vou tratar o parâmetro recebido e então executar um script chamado "ligar.js" ou "desligar.js". Estes scripts estarão na mesma pasta do servidor. Imaginei que em "File System" haveria algo como a função "exec()" do PHP, mas não encontrei. No PHP, por exemplo, poderia ser feito algo como `exec( "/meu_path/meu_script.js $onOff");`. Como faço essa execução de um script no Node?

Comment: Acho que isso resolve seu problema https://udgwebdev.com/node-js-para-leigos-child-process/

Comment: Rafael, grato pelo retorno. Acho que isso resolve o problema e achei muito útil. Porém acabei fazendo apenas com o `require` como sugeriu o colega Sérgio na outra resposta. Já consegui daquela forma. Obrigado!

Comment: tranquilo, se resolveu fico feliz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se queres executar um script `.js` o melhor é criares funções nesses scripts e fazer `require` ou `import` desses scripts para poderes correr essas funções quando for preciso.

Se os scripts não forem JavaScript podes fazer assim, uma sugestão que aceita vários comandos e os corre sequencialmente:

```js
"use strict;"

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

const commands = [
 'sudo comando1',
 'sudo comando2'
];

function runCommand(cmds, cb){
 const next = cmds.shift();
 if (!next) return cb();
 exec(next, {
  cwd: __dirname
 }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
  if (err && !next.match(/\-s$/)) {
   console.log(`O commando "${next}" falhou.`, err);
   cb(err);
  }
  else runCommand(cmds, cb);
 });
}

runCommand(commands, err => {
 console.log('Script corrido');
});
```

Se quiseres correr somente 1 comando podes simplificar e fazer assim:

```js
"use strict;"

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
const cmd = 'sudo comando1';

exec(cmd, {
  cwd: __dirname
}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else runCommand(cmds, cb);
});
```

Comment: Sérgio, você tem razão. apenas o `require` já resolve, mas de qualquer forma o que você e o colega Rafael sugeriram sobre o `child_process`é muito legal e útil. Obrigado.

Comment: @wBB ótimo que ajudou. O script que coloquei aqui é para vários comandos. Juntei agora uma versão simplificada para somente 1 comando.